# Unable to add role into openiddict jwt token

Tags: c#, jwt, roles, openiddict

I'd like to create a jwt token containing role=root using openiddict.

```
{
  "aud": "audience_01",
  "client_id": "client_01",
  "role": "root",
  "scope": "scope_01"
}
```

Here is the payload of the jwt token I am currently getting back. It does not contain the expected role=root:

```
{
  "sub": "client_01",
  "oi_prst": "client_01",
  "client_id": "client_01",
  "oi_tkn_id": "2179f976-89f3-49ba-bb86-cefa0523a627",
  "aud": "audience_01",
  "scope": "scope_01",
  "jti": "fa97eaf2-4716-45fa-9f03-aab977873386",
  "exp": 1701893995,
  "iss": "https://localhost:22401/",
  "iat": 1701807595
}
```

I'm using the following code:

```
[HttpPost("~/connect/token")]
public async ValueTask<IActionResult> Exchange()
{
    //retrieve OIDC request from original request
    var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

    if (request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType())
    {
        var clientId = request.ClientId;
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType: TokenValidationParameters.DefaultAuthenticationType,
            nameType: Claims.Name,
            roleType: Claims.Role
            );

        identity.AddClaim(Claims.Subject, clientId);
        identity.AddClaim(Claims.Name, "claims_name");
        identity.AddClaim(Claims.Role, "root");

        identity.SetScopes(request.GetScopes());
        identity.SetResources(await _scopeManager.ListResourcesAsync(identity.GetScopes()).ToListAsync());
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        // Returning a SignInResult will ask OpenIddict to issue the appropriate access/identity tokens.
        return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    throw new NotImplementedException("The specified grant type is not implemented.");
}
```

Comment: Show us what the actual generated JWT looks like.

Comment: Are you sure that `SetResources` isn't overwriting/clearing the `Role` claim?

Comment: I've added the payload of the JWT being returned in my post.  When I comment out the SetScopes and SetResources, I get a similar payload, except it is now missing the aud and scope.

Comment: Exactly what method is `SignIn(principal, ...)` referencing?

Comment: The Exchange function to get the token is based off of an example I found for generating tokens using OpenIddict.  I think SignIn is part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc or an OpenIddict library.  I'm not an expert with OpenIddict, so that's as much as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claims don't have a `destination` attached so OpenIddict won't copy them to the access tokens it will produce based on your `ClaimsPrincipal`.

See https://documentation.openiddict.com/guides/getting-started.html for an example showing how to call `SetDestinations()`.